# Is it possible to use voice match function

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

Is it possible to use voice match function when using Google Assistant SDK?

According to the documentation of the Google Assistant SDK, I installed a Google Assistant in Windows.（ https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview ）

However, we can not use speaker identification of voice matches.
Is there a way to use the Voice Match function using the Google Assistant SDK?

Answer (score 1):

No, speaker identification is not a feature that is directly supported in the Google Assistant SDK. On a Google Home, an on-device machine learning model is used to identify each user. While you could develop your own implementation, it is not something that is provided as part of the platform.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm thinking if I add my device as smart speaker, I can use voice match function. because it seems third party speaker have voice match function. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkIvn5aWfpY&t=219s

I got AIY-Project Kit. But Google doesn't allow to register my speaker as "Smart Speaker". They just allow us to set "light", "switch"...

How to set-up my speaker as smart speaker?

Comment: The voice match capability (along with the integrated setup) are part of a deeper integration with the Assistant SDK than what is currently possible with the publicly available APIs.